# GoogleMaps Api and C#

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps-api-3, webbrowser-control

i have problem with my map. Map was working correctly about 5 months ago. Now when I load map with my coords, map is loading, but when i start browsing map, zooming etc. i'm getting white screen like there's no connection with map.. i need to load map again, but again this same problem happens. About 5 months ago i was using this script and everything was working fine.. browsing, zooming, change map type, everything without any problems. I've created html code according to google website and put it in new resource file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">



  function load(latitude,longitude,zoomik) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: zoomik,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng, 
        map: map,
        title:"Here!"});

  }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for my button is:

```
  private void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("load", new object[] { -34.397, 150.644, 8 });
    }
```

Screens: 
Map loaded correctly:
[image]

After use of pan tool or zoom tool: - blank white screen.
[image]

I'm using Visual C# Express and WebBrowser control from winforms.

HTML code is working correctly in Firefox (using Aptana Studio) (zoom and pan working ok)

What more this code from google api example is also not working correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css"        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
     zoom: 8,
     center: myLatlng,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
   }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this myself.

Wrong was:

```html
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

after changing it to:

```html
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:400px"></div>
```

map is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

When i have problems with gMaps the first thing i do is changing the map key, did you try this? Which browsers did you try? Firefox, Chrome or IE ?

Comment: Well, i'm using WebBrowser from winforms in visual. API key? According to GoogleMaps API website: "This version of the Google Maps JavaScript API no longer needs API keys!". HTML code was working correctly in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Google Maps v3.  Although, my problem was that I was targeting the current Google Maps v3 API and they "deprecated" a called to `set_map` and introduced the same functionality as `setMap`.

I don't see anything in your code which should be broken.  If you have other JavaScript on this page throwing an error, it can sometimes cause Google Maps to not load.  For instance, if you reference some other JavaScript which throws an uncaught exception, the map may not load.

My suggestion is to specify the version of Google Maps API instead of using the current and see if that fixes it:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.3&sensor=false">
</script>
```

Edit: also, looking at your post again, you may want to move the logic for setting a marker and map zoom out of the load function.  That way, when you click the button, you're not re-initializing the map and options. I saw on the on documentation the other day that the map now has a "clear" options for the div contents, and loading the map twice (body load, button click) may be forcing that clear behavior.  Again, target a previous API version and it may work.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could instead load google maps in Flash and not in a WebBrowser object? The following link explains how to do it using WPF, but it should be easily applicable to WinForms: http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/articles/flashmapinwpf.html